# How to get UIView size in a Xamarin Forms custom renderer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uiview, xamarin.ios

I created a custom view renderer in Xamarin Forms and would like to know the size of the view so that I can add subviews with absolute positioning.

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<MyView> e)
{
     base.OnElementChanged(e);

     if (e.NewElement != null)
     {
         if (Control == null)
         {
             var uiView = new UIView
             {
                 BackgroundColor = UIColor.SystemPinkColor
             };

             SetNativeControl(uiView);

             // How to get uiView width and height in absolute numbers?
         }
     }
}
```

When I check `uiView.Frame`, I'm getting 0 for width and height.

In PCL, `MyView` is displayed as a child of a `Grid` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for can not getting the `size` of View from `OnElementChanged` method , because this method is the same as `ViewDidLoad` method . The frame of View hasn't been calculated in this stage.

We can get `width` and `height` from `Draw` method , this stage viewcontroller will begin to draw view on screen according to the size of frame .**Therefore** we can definitely get the size now .

```
UIView uIView;

public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
{
    base.Draw(rect);
    Console.WriteLine("------------x" + uIView.Frame.Size.Width);
    Console.WriteLine("------------x" + Control.Frame.Size.Width);
    Console.WriteLine("------------x" + Control.Bounds.Size.Width);
}
```

Or other methods whose lifecycle is after `OnElementChanged` .Such as `LayoutSubviews` method:

```
UIView uIView;

public override void LayoutSubviews()
{
    base.LayoutSubviews();

    Console.WriteLine("------------" + uIView.Frame.Size.Width);
    Console.WriteLine("------------" + Control.Frame.Size.Width);
    Console.WriteLine("------------" + Control.Bounds.Size.Width);
}
```

Output :

```
2020-06-16 10:59:11.327982+0800 AppFormsTest.iOS[30355:821323] ------------375
2020-06-16 10:59:11.328271+0800 AppFormsTest.iOS[30355:821323] ------------375
2020-06-16 10:59:11.328497+0800 AppFormsTest.iOS[30355:821323] ------------375
```